# Replacing a certain character by position on a certain line in linux CLI

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I want to replace a certain character on a certain line with another, the character must be identified by number and not by identity.

Say I wanted to modify this so that the 2nd `*` on the 4th line is an `X`

```
****\n****\n****\n****
```

so it would look like this

```
****\n****\n****\n*X**
```

Since every character is a `*` I cannot differentiate the characters, so I want to do it by position. Is there anyway I can do this?

Answer (score 2):

With GNU sed:

```
row="4"
col="2"
sed -E "${row}"'s/(.{'"$(($col-1))"'})./\1X/' file
```

Input (file):

```
****
****
****
****
```

Output:

```
****
****
****
*X**
```

Comment: You can substitute the nth occurence with `s` command with sed with `s/bre/rep/<number>`. It's just `"$row"'s/./X/'"$((col-1))"`

Comment: I wouldn't use `sed` here. `awk` should be used since it can do it without using regular expressions. Especially since the question is tagged as `awk` I see no reason to advertise `sed` here.

Answer (score 0):

The Perl version is pretty readable:

```
perl -pe 'substr($_,2,1)="X" if $.==3' file
****
****
**X*
****
```

You only need to know that `$_` represents the contents of the current line and `$.` represents the line number.

Comment: You replaced the wrong character in the wrong line. omg!, all my data is lost now. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use `awk`, since it can do it without using a regular expression which makes it very efficient.

With `gawk` you can use the null string `-F ''` as the delimiter to split the input line by characters:

```
gawk -v ln=4 -v col=2 -v val='X' -F '' 'BEGIN{OFS=""}NR==ln{$col=val}1' file
```

Posixly correct and therefore portable would be:

```
awk -v ln=4 -v col=2 -v val='X' \
    'NR==ln{printf "%s%s%s\n",substr($0,1,col-1),val,substr($0,col+1);next}1' file
```

Comment: Funnily enough, I did exactly that earlier but omitted to set `OFS` and it all came out double-spaced!

Comment: I often wish that awk would use `OFS=FS` by default, if `FS` is a fixed string. But I'm sure EdMorton could explain why that's a bad idea :)

Comment: Reading https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/417122/57293 , is `awk` the  right tool here?

Comment: @WalterA That's a good point. The behaviour if FS is a null string is undefined by posix. Looks `substr()` needs to be used to be posix conform. Let me add that